# rails script/server doesn't start the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded, setup all the gems for http://github.com/bestbuyremix/BBYIDX

Now when I type:

rails script/server

I got the output, but server doesn't start??

```
create  
      create  app/controllers
      create  app/helpers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts
      create  config/environments
      create  config/initializers
      create  db
      create  doc
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  log
      create  public/images
      create  public/javascripts
      create  public/stylesheets
      create  script/performance
      create  script/process
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/functional
      create  test/integration
      create  test/unit
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  tmp/sessions
      create  tmp/sockets
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/pids
      create  Rakefile
      create  README
      create  app/controllers/application.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  script/about
      create  script/console
      create  script/dbconsole
      create  script/destroy
      create  script/generate
      create  script/performance/benchmarker
      create  script/performance/profiler
      create  script/performance/request
      create  script/process/reaper
      create  script/process/spawner
      create  script/process/inspector
      create  script/runner
      create  script/server
      create  script/plugin
      create  public/dispatch.rb
      create  public/dispatch.cgi
      create  public/dispatch.fcgi
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  public/images/rails.png
      create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      create  public/javascripts/effects.js
      create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      create  public/javascripts/controls.js
      create  public/javascripts/application.js
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  log/server.log
      create  log/production.log
      create  log/development.log
      create  log/test.log
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prior to Rails 3, the job of the `rails` script was simply to create a new RoR app, which is all you're doing: Creating a new Rails app in the `script/server` directory.

You want to run `ruby script/server` to invoke the server script with the Ruby interpreter.

In Rails 3, the `rails` script is also responsible for invoking other scripts within your app: `ruby script/server` has become `rails server`, `ruby script/generate` has become `rails generate` and so on.

Comment: ah! so what is the file/folder I should be deleting here?

Comment: I would imagine you have a "server" folder inside your script directory containing a rails app; you should delete that.

Comment: "If you get a command not found error when running this command(rails generate), you need to explicitly pass Rails rails commands to Ruby: ruby \path\to\your\application\script\rails generate controller home index"