# rails command doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried to start the rails server with this line:

```
$ rails s
  create                                                                                                                                                                
  create  app/controllers                                                                                                                                               
  create  app/helpers                                                                                                                                                   
  create  app/models                                                                                                                                                    
  create  app/views/layouts                                                                                                                                             
  create  config/environments                                                                                                                                           
  ...                                                                                                                                          
  create  log/test.log
```

But if I write down this:

```
$ script/rails s                                                                                                                    
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:138: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick                                                                                                                                                          
=> Rails 3.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
...
```

Anyone can see the problem? I think is a problem with environment variables, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this problem. I was switching from a Windows environment to Linux. My Linux version of rails is 2.3.14 while my Windows version was 3.0.1. On Windows "rails s" or "rails server" worked as expected to start a server, but on Linux it just created new projects with the names "s" and "Server" respectively. What finally explained it is the answer to the question below. Apparently the command behavior was changed between rails versions.

[rails script/server doesn't start the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949855/rails-script-server-doesnt-start-the-server)

The best solution is probably to update to the latest rails.

I was able to do that on my linux box by following the instructions below and using "**sudo gem install rails**"

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/ubuntu

http://root2linux.com/2011/01/install-rails-3-on-linux-mint-10/

Answer (score 1):

this issue come from the different version in rvm, I faced this issue when my app was created using rvm 1.9.2 and I tried to run the server while rvm 1.9.3 was the running rvm version, simply switch to rvm1.9.2 and all will work properly (rvm use 1.9.2) in the terminal in ubunutu

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a rails application directory? When you're running `rails s` make sure you've `cd`'d into the correct Rails directory. Common problem :)

Comment: Yes, I am :( ... That's why script/rails works, because I am in ./script/rails

Comment: Well, I "fixed" with an alias, `alias rails='script/rails'` but I'd rather a real solution.

Comment: I'm still confused why you are using 'script/rails', is 'rails' the name of your Rails application? If so, Rails is a reserved word.

Comment: And when you run `rails s` in your example at the top, it should not be creating an application structure, it should be running a server on an application. To start your server, you do not need to call `script/rails s` but only `rails s` from within your application directory.

Comment: yes, but I don't know why it doesn't work. It used to work but now I have this problem.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what exactly is going on. When you run `rails s`, it should NOT be creating a rails application. You are showing in your question that `rails s` is creating an application, this is not true. Regardless of what used to work, why are you trying to call `script/rails s`? If you are running Rails 3, then you just say `rails s`, leave off the 'script'. You need to re-write your question almost entirely. The more information we have, the more likely we are to be able to help you.